# NSAttributedString as a Transformable Attribute in Core Data Entity

Tags: cocoa, core-data

In the Core Data Programming Guide under "Transformable Attributes" [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html).
It is stated "You can now use the attribute as you would any other standard attribute, as illustrated in the following code fragment:"
The follow line of code is listed `newEmployee.favoriteColor = [NSColor redColor];`

I am trying to do something similar in my code but it doesn't work. Here is my code:
In Entry.h:

```
@interface Entry :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSAttributedString * contentString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject * journal;

@end
```

and in Entry.m:

```
@implementation Entry 

@dynamic contentString;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic journal;

- (void)awakeFromInsert {
   [super awakeFromInsert];
   self.date = [NSDate date];
}

@end
```

Elsewhere I have this code:

```
Entry *newEntry =
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entry"
        inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
newEntry.contentString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"MyString"] autorelease];
newEntry.journal = self.journal;
```

The line

```
newEntry.contentString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"MyString"] autorelease];
```

is equivalent to

```
newEmployee.favoriteColor = [NSColor redColor];
```

As far as I can tell however this doesn't work. I get a runtime error:

> 2010-10-13 09:02:08.577 JournalMaker[2437:a0f] Cannot create NSData
>   from object MyString{ } of class NSConcreteAttributedString

I have no idea what this error message is supposed to mean. Can someone explain?

Comment: Show us how you have the property modelled, that's the important info in this case.

Comment: How should it be modelled? We have it set as an id, but we tried NSAttributedString and that didn't work either...